# Can we pass the HttpGet query string implicitly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, query-string, model-binding, http-get

So I created MVC 4 app with Database First and Entity Framework approach.I have created respective Models,Controllers and Views(By adding MVC controller with read/write actions and views, using Entity Framework template). So it comes with Create,Delete,Edit,Index and Details Views and respective action methods.
[image]

When I click on Details,Edit or Delete I see that location id which is a parameter in action method is not passed passed with value, so only default value 0 is used. and I learned that with HttpGet we need to pass it as query string in URL,but in my case how can I implicitly pass the Location ID for Edit/Details or Delete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do it like this:

VIEW:

```
foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "EditAction", new {id = item._account})
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "DetailsAction", new {id = item._account})
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "DeleteAction", new {id = item._account})
        </td>
   </tr>

}
```

CONTROLLER:

```
    //
    // GET: /Controller/EditAction/id 
    public ActionResult EditAction(int id)
    {
         //Do Something
    }

    //
    // GET: /Controller/DetailsAction/id 
    public ActionResult DetailsAction(int id)
    {
         //Do Something
    }

    //
    // GET: /Controller/DeleteAction/id 
    public ActionResult DeleteAction(int id)
    {
            //Do Something
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

the list View template's links are created using @Html.ActionLink right ? If so, they have to respectively contain the item Id they intend to point to explicitely, so they should be something like
    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", new {id=item.Id}))
Which is correct if you use the default Route.

By the way I am surprised these links do not contain the right Id setup by default in list templates.

Comment: By default they didn't contain it,Now I passed new {id=item.LocationId} and it works